# What is the difference between negative acceleration and decreasing acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

According to Reisnick and Halliday, retardation is the acceleration in the negative direction of time axis ie. opposite to the motion. Decreasing accleretion is the decrease in the magnitude of time rate of change of velocity. Am I correct or not? What is the $v$-$t$ graph with retardation and decreasing acceleration? [I don't think they are same.]

Comment: One of them says that the second derivative of position is negative, the other says that the third derivative is negative. These two things are different because $2\neq 3$ or, equivalently, $1+1\neq 3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example, particle moving in one dimension, say $x$:

A particle has a (**negative**) acceleration equal to $-2m/s^2$ (**note** it is constant acceleration, yet negative, i.e opposite to direction of motion or to direction of cummulant force applied to particle)

Another particle has a (**decreasing**) acceleration equal to $1/(kt)^2 m/s^2$ (**note** it is positive acceleration i.e in the same direction as direction of motion, yet decreasing in magnitude with time)

To sum up, negative or opposite acceleration refers to direction, while decreasing acceleration refers to magnitude.

The above are only illustrative examples, many more examples of negative and decreasing accelerations (or both).

Some mock v-t graphs for various types of acceleration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ Nikos M. :  So sir ,can i say i am correct? Plz tell me what will be their respective v-t graphs . Thank u.

Comment: @user36790, yes you are correct. Negative acceleration is **opposite** acceleration, related to direction of motion. Whereas decreasing acceleration refers to **magnitude** and **not direction**. The v-t graph can have many shapes since an acceleration can be both negative and decreasing or none. For the examples i gave, in 1st case the velocity will have constant negative slope, so at some point it will reverse, while in 2nd case the velocity **will not** reverse, but at some point will become constant (acceleration will become zero)

Comment: @user36790, added mock v-t graphs for elucidation

Comment: @ Nikos M : Very,very,thank u! Sir can u tell me when the slope of the v-t graph is negative(eg $tan 150$ ),what does the negative sign tell about? Does it tell the direction of acceleration is negative? Again thanks!

Comment: @user36790, acceleration **is** the slope of the v-t curve (for one-dimensional motion), so connstant negative acceleration means the v-t curve has constant negative slope as shown in graph 2. Negative refers to direction